# Rails generate model inside engine not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I just initialized a new rails 4.0.1 with the following command:

```
rails plugin new gossiper -T --dummy-path=spec/dummy
```

When I try to generate a model I get the rails g help, telling me that I am not inside an rails app.

```
rails g model Notification user_id:integer

Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

### Edit

I just realized I missed the --mountable params. Sorry.

Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I missed the --mountable params. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to issue the command from within a rails console and NOT the terminal.

Run "rails c" and try again.